# How bad is it to have image strings embedded directly in my HTML?

Tags: php, html, image, performance

Let's say I'm making some kind of PHP-based single-page image board that shows 100 small (<10kb) user-uploaded images. The oldest image is deleted from the server as soon as a new image is uploaded. Because the images come and go so rapidly I feel like there's not much of an advantage to caching them. It occurs to me that I could just embed the images as strings directly in the page's HTML, and that would also minimize the number of requests to my server. However, I feel like this must be a "bad thing". I'm wondering what input you knowledgeable folks have? Thank you!

Comment: Just wondering if someone has knowledge of this off the top of their head.

Comment: Can you show some code about what you mean?

Comment: @robertgfthomas: *every* performance optimization success or fail story is *unique*. So it always is necessary to measure, otherwise you will not be able to even tell if you made it worse or better.

Comment: Isn't a bad thing to store them via `data:image/xx`. The problem is you're using lots of them and even if you're serving HTML compressed this falls because your images are probably JPG which cant really compressed anymore. In my opinion, you gain on performance but you lose on download speed.

Answer (score 1):

It will be faster as much less connections are used. But you need to ask yourself if one particular user browsing through your site will see those images more than once, if yes than let the Web Server do the rest ( 304 response or similar )

Comment: "It will be faster" --- What "it"? The page will be served *slower*, because of the bigger size + additional encoding required

Comment: If you time test Real Page Load including HTML,JS,CSS,Images etc it will be faster if you embed image data into HTML. Try it with [YSlow](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/yslow/) and see. Less time for user, fewer requests to server. On the other hand if HTML is only served, user will be able to see text sooner and images later which may be more user friendly way.

Comment: I agree that something will be faster. My point is that "it" does not point to anything explicitly. And when you discuss performance optimizations you should be very careful when you refer to something vague without naming it explicitly.